# Is it a topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

please can you tel me
if this is a topology :

$$\theta=\{\mathbb{R},\emptyset\}\cup \{E_a=]a,+\infty[\}_{a\in \mathbb{R}^*}$$

i think that no , if we take the sequence $\{a_n\}=\{\frac1n\}$ then $\bigcup_{n} E_{a_n}=]\inf{a_n},+\infty[=]0,+\infty[\notin \theta$

but in the exercise i have i must prove that $\theta$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Thank you

Comment: What is $E_a =] a$ and what is $[$?

Comment: @Misakov Symbol $]a,b[$ is an open interval from $a$ to $b$ as opposed to a closed interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: ? $E_a$ is the interval $]a,+\infty[$ with $a\in \mathbb{R}^*=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: $\theta$ is a topology iff it satisfies three criteria: 1. $\emptyset, \mathbb{R} \in \theta$, 2. For every $A, B \in \theta$, $A\cap B \in \theta$, 3. For every subset $S \subseteq \theta$, $\cup S \in \theta$.

Comment: yes and i give a example where the stape 3 is false

Comment: @EvanAad are you agree with me ?

Comment: If you gave the definition of $\theta$ correctly, and if $\Bbb R^*$ really does denote $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, then your counterexample is correct. If $E_a$ is open for each $a>0$, then $E_0$ must be open.

Comment: I suspect that $\mathbb{R}^*$ does not denote the nonzero reals, but rather the [*extended real line*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line). If so, the problem is correct (but including $\mathbb{R}$ and $\emptyset$ in $\theta$ is unnecessary).

Comment: @NoahSchweber $R^*=R\setminus\{0\}$ it is the french notation

Comment: @EvanAad i take a sequence from $\mathbb{R}^*$ which is $\{\frac1n\}$ and i consider $E_{a_n}=]\frac1n, +\infty$ and this family is from $\theta$

Comment: Are you sure that the "$\mathbb R$" in "$\{\mathbb R, \phi \}$" in the def'n of $\theta$ wasn't meant to be "$\mathbb R^+$" ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou If everything is as you've written it, Brian Scott is correct: the exercise is wrong, for the reason you point out.

Comment: Perhaps the source of the problem has a typo, in which a period at the end of the sentence defining $\theta$ got turned into a star.